# How do I build an Ant script to do different compilations based on my target output. AIR vs Swf?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ant, air, flash-builder

How can I build an Ant script to output swfs vs air packages, and to use different classes during the compilation based on my desired destination?

For example I am building an app that will be for the web, mobile and desktop.  In some cases my classes will use AIR only components.  I want to be able to create ANT build scripts that will not include those classes when outputting a swf for the web.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did for a similar situation:

```
<target name="define.compile.task" depends="initflex">
    <presetdef name="flex.build">
        <mxmlc file="${src.dir}/${src.file.path}" 
                output="${output.dir}/${output.file.path}" ...>
            <compiler.source-path path-element="${src.dir}"/>
            ...
        </mxmlc>
    </presetdef>
</target>

<target name="parametrized.web.build" depends="define.compile.task">
    <flex.build>
        <compiler.define name="CONFIG::AllowAirComponents" value="false" />
    </flex.build>   
</target>


<target name="parametrized.air.build" depends="define.compile.task">
    <flex.build configname="airmobile">
        <compiler.define name="CONFIG::AllowAirComponents" value="true" />
    </flex.build>   
</target>
```

Then, I could define targets like

```
<target name="buildwebclass1">
     <antcall target="parametrized.web.build">
          <param name="src.file.path" value="path/to/MyClass.as"/>
          <param name="output.file.path" value="MyClass.swf"/>
     </antcall>
</target>
```

Or:

```
<target name="buildairclass1">
     <antcall target="parametrized.air.build">
          <param name="src.file.path" value="path/to/MyAirClass.as"/>
          <param name="output.file.path" value="MyAirClass.swf"/>
     </antcall>
     <exec executable="${FLEX_HOME}/bin/adt" failonerror="true">
         ... (adt arguments)
     </exec>
</target>
```

And if I have some factory of common code that instantiates the air class only if necessary, I wrap it with a `CONFIG::AllowAirComponents { ... }` so my AIR specific classes wouldn't interfere with the web build.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oooh, thanks.  Do you wrap the import statements in CONFIG::AllowAirComponents or just the instantiation of the classes?  Also if I'm using Robotlegs and the [Inject] MetaData can I wrap the CONFIG::AllowAir around the Injection metadata as well or will it conflict?

Comment: Well... In my case the relevant code is in the same package so I didn't need to import. I don't know about injection as well - you'll have to try and let us know how it goes...

Comment: Bob, the non-used imports should be ignored at compile time, so u don't need to care about them. Regarding Robotlegs: not sure about Inject metatag + conditional compilation, but maybe u'd better review architecture a bit? E.g. inject against interface, but define appropriate mapping via conditional compilation. Alternatively, if u inject against real classes — there should be no problems if u map "right" classes via conditional compilation.